# How to custom table data in views in drupal 8

Tags: drupal

I have a custom table with 3-4 fields. I want to create a view that will display the custom table data. I have created a module.view.inc file but not getting how to proceed further.

I have a custom table with 3-4 fields. I want to create a view that will display the custom table data. I have created a module.view.inc file but not getting how to proceed further.

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Views Custom Table module](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_custom_table) to do this for you.

Alternatively you can use [hook_views_data](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/8.2.x) to do that